# Deploying ASP.NET 5 application with backing DB on client servers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I'm writing an ASP.NET 5 application targetting .Net Core using EF7. When I'm done, I'd like to publish the application to a platform-specific installer that, when run, will install a service, deploy a database based on user-input credentials for a SQL Server. The service will self-host the ASP.NET application.

Is this possible? How would I go about achieving this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We use [MSDeploy at work](https://dotnetcatch.wordpress.com/2015/04/22/extending-msdeploy-beyond-the-web/) to deploy all of our components: web applications, windows services, scheduled task, SQL databases, etc.

You could use the following command to [package up the service code](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207412(v=ws.10).aspx):

```
msdeploy -verb:sync -source:dirPath=/path/to/service -dest:package=servicePackage.zip -verbose
```

And this command to deploy it to the target:

```
msdeploy -verb:sync -source:package=/path/to/service -dest:package=servicePackage.zip -verbose
```

Use a database project for the SQL database and create a DacPac to publish.  You can use [MSDeploy to publish the DacPac](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569036(v=ws.10).aspx):

```
MSDeploy –verb: MSDeploy-verb –source:dbSqlPackage="db.dacpac"[,dbSqlPackage-source-parameters] –dest:dpSqlPackage="TargetConnectionString"[,dbSqlPackage-target-parameters]
```

Finally use [Manifests](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569104(v=ws.10).aspx) to wrap it all up into a single MSDeploy package.

Regarding the user input values for the database, I would use [WebDeploy Parameterization](http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy/web-deploy-parameterization) files to define the variables and apply them to the database deployment.  These parameterization files can be used for non-web deployments via MSDeploy.  Then write some PowerShell to wrap the MSDeploy command for deployment to prompt the user for their inputs and edit the SetParameters file.